# How do I embed a Google Drive document into my Weebly site?

Tags: embed, weebly

I'm trying to embed my resume into a page on my weebly website. I've saved the file as a pdf, allowed link sharing, and followed the steps [for embedding documents from Google docs](https://christopher.su/2012/embedding-documents-google-docs/). I've gotten as far as getting the file to display within the weebly app, but it doesn't appear live on the site once I publish it. The page just appears blank, though additional space appears to be taken up. Perhaps an important note is that I'm using my ipad to do this.

Here is the custom HTML code I'm using within iframe generated from the above mentioned website:

`<iframe style="width: 900px; height: 900px;" src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://ivanglinski.weebly.com/uploads/5/7/9/5/57950797/ivan_glinski_resume_3_24.pdf&embedded=true" height="240" width="320" frameborder="0">`

Answer (score 0):

Every Weebly site comes with an "Embed Code" element which is available in the Weebly Editor (while building/editing/updating your site and its pages).

1. Get the "embed code" from Google for the GDrive doc you want to embed.
2. Drag an instance of the "Embed Code" element onto the page of your Weebly site where you want the GDrive doc to be displayed.
3. Click on the element you just instantiated, and paste the "embed code" from Google for the GDrive doc (from step 1) into the appropriate configuration field of the Embed Code element.
4. Publish your site
5. Test things are working, and if not, you may need to adjust permissions on the GDrive doc.